# R - Download Data from Webpage

Tags: r, http-post

I want to download CSV file from a webpage, where I have to select the time frame described by the data as well as the columns I want to download.

The page is the following:

https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.asp?Table_ID=258&DB_Short_Name=Air%20Carriers

I wanted to ask, how I can achieve downloading this table for years 2015 and 2016, with columns passenger, carrier, origin and dest.

Using the Chrome Developer Tool I found out, that when clicking upon the button "Download", a function "TryDownload()" is being called in the background, which should be callable using a POST request. However, I dont understand, how I can call this function using R as well as changing the default selected columns.

Thank you for your help.